# Portlet is unregistered (memory leak?)

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-ide

I created new project (*Liferay Project with Plugin Portlet Type and JSF 2.x.x Portlet Framework*) using Lifeay IDE in Eclipse. I didn't change anything and added project to *Liferay v6.1 CE Server (Tomcat 7)* and started this server.

Unfortunately, I got this errors (portlet was unregistered).

> (...) 09:05:08,828 INFO  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]][PluginPackageUtil:1033] Reading plugin package for MyFaces-portlet
>   2013-08-02 09:05:09 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   09:05:09,037 INFO  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]][HookHotDeployListener:813] **Hook for MyFaces-portlet was unregistered**
>   2013-08-02 09:05:09 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
>   **SEVERE: The web application [/MyFaces-portlet] appears to have started a thread named [MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.**
>   09:05:26,970 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageUtil][PluginPackageUtil:1421] Checking for available updates
>   09:05:26,971 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageUtil][PluginPackageUtil:1465] Finished checking for available updates in 1 ms

What is wrong?

Comment: How did you added project to server?Did you build ant script or what?

Comment: I integrated Tomcat with Eclipse (by New server). It is described here http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/set-up

Comment: Same deal here, did you find a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score -1):

You have to build the project using ANT script. when you create the portlet, build.xml gets created. It looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE project>
<project name="abc-portlet" basedir="." default="deploy">
     <import file="../build-common-portlet.xml" />
</project>
```

you have to build this file using ant. when you build it successfully, your portlet war will be created on SDKPlugins\dist folder. And Automatically deploy to the server. It is hot deployment you need not have to add any thing. Every time new WAS gets deployed, you will get the message that 'abc-portlet' was unregistered and then new version get deployed.

So Do not worry if you got the message for undeployment. It will be deployed.

About message, portlet was unregistered it generally comes when Portlet is not deployed successfully.

Comment: I don't think his error is related to this since he used the Liferay IDE which uses Liferay SDK (with Ant). The error is about the "memory leak" problem, which is not understandable here.